# translating logical quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Let a = “A is working,” b = “B is working,” and c = “C is working.” Write the three status reports in terms of a, b, and c, using the symbols of formal logic.

*Processor A reports that Processor B is not working and Processor C is working*.

a = ~B ^ C

*Processor B reports that Processor A is working if and only if Processor B is working.*

b = A iff B

*Processor C reports that at least one of the other two processors is not working*

c = (~∀x)Wx

I need to express a,b,c using a truth table but I am confused as how to express c as it does not include variables a nor b. Is there another way to write c? or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

> > Processor C reports that at least one of the other two processors is not working
>
> I am confused as how to express c as it does not include variables a nor b. Is there another way to write c? or have I made a mistake?

To restate Processor C's report: "either : A is not working, *or* B is not working".  Can you write that?

Comment: would  it be ~(A v B) ?

Comment: @NoahDeng Close, but not quite.  That says: "its not true that either A or B are working." (aka "both A and B are not working").

Comment: so remove the brackets to have ~A v ~B?

Comment: @NoahDeng I think that is what Graham meant. My way of thinking about it is kind of roundabout, but it may help (if it makes no sense ignore me): If at least one of the other two processors is not working, then we know that `it is NOT that case that both of them are working`. That is, ~(A ^B). **If you haven't learned demorgans laws this will not make sense, but...**, ~(A^B) is the same as ~A v ~B

Answer (score 2):

You don't need quantifiers at all, you just need to write what the status reports are. They are:

1. $\neg b \land c$
2. $a\leftrightarrow b$
3. $\neg a\lor \neg b$.

Comment: $\neg R(A,B)$ would be that "processor A does not report that processor B is working". You're over complicating matters. These processors *are* reporting logical formula (or at least that their formula is satisfied). These formulae have been given in English, the task is to represent them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Not to worry, I killed all that, as being overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You already know that

1. "B is not working" translates to $\neg B$
2. "at least one" translates to "A or B"

Just piece it together. There's no need for quantifiers.

Comment: I thought not initially, but what about the "reports" nonsense? :)

Comment: Perhaps we can assume that if a processor is able to report something, it is currently working.

Comment: I was delusional: the question says, write what the status reports are. So, right, no fussing with the "reports" relation, no quantifiers.